Problem with pdf export from Elevation Profile View tool in QGIS
I created an elevation profile of a pit that is to be dug and the current terrain using the Elevation Profile View tool in QGIS. The results I get in the tool preview are as desired and look like this:

Now when trying to export this graph to a pdf file, only the top left corner is being printed. I used the default export-to-pdf-settings for an A4 landscape format sheet, which seem reasonable to me after checking them. The result however looks like this:

How can I export all of the graph to pdf as shown in the preview of the tool?
